# Vue: Select dropdown is clearing other inputs when changing value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form with input values.  When I have a select with a v-model on it and go to change the drop down value, the input from the previous fields clear.  I made a simple codepen to demonstrate this.  It's been a pain point for me for a while but now it's starting to interfere with customer experience so I'd like to see why this happens.

https://codepen.io/lorvenji9533/pen/VwvVBMV

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input></input>
      <select v-model="foo">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: ""
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Need to see your vue methods used. Just giving us html doesn't help much.

Comment: sorry, just added

Comment: Taking a look, I can't immediately see anything, though you're also not showing your entire Vue component code. Which specific field are resetting? Where else are they referred to in your code? What kind of debugging have you tried already?

Comment: @LannyBose all of `input` elements clear when I change the dropdown value.  I tried throwing a debugger statement in to trace the flow when the dropdown value changes but I see nothing suspicious at all

Comment: @LannyBose here's a codepen that demonstrates https://codepen.io/lorvenji9533/pen/VwvVBMV .  I think it's the simple fact that having a v-model on the select does it but I can't see why.

Comment: Doesn't do anything strange for me. The value entered into the `<input>` remains after making a selection. Could this be due to your browser's auto-complete feature? Try the suggestions here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: FYI, `<input>` does not have a closing tag. Try just `<input>` or `<input />`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for me the problem was that I saved the value of the text input in a prop, but it should be saved in the data method.

So the element looks like:

```
<input v-model="value"/>
```

End then in the script part:

```
data() {
    return {
        value: ''
    }
}
```